# Mysql select - where - order by clause (for Prestashop)

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, where-clause, prestashop

For those familiar with Prestashop, I am trying to add an extra sort order option in the category view. More specifically I want to add extra sort order for a selection of features.

This is the main part of the prestashop query to get the products: (the last column in the SELECT part as well as the last JOIN added by me)

```
$sql = 'SELECT p.*, product_shop.*, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, MAX(product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute) id_product_attribute, product_attribute_shop.minimal_quantity AS product_attribute_minimal_quantity, pl.`description`, pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`,
                    pl.`available_later`, pl.`link_rewrite`, pl.`meta_description`, pl.`meta_keywords`, pl.`meta_title`, pl.`name`, MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image,
                    il.`legend`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, cl.`name` AS category_default,
                    DATEDIFF(product_shop.`date_add`, DATE_SUB(NOW(),
                    INTERVAL '.(Validate::isUnsignedInt(Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT')) ? Configuration::get('PS_NB_DAYS_NEW_PRODUCT') : 20).'
                        DAY)) > 0 AS new, product_shop.price AS orderprice, fp.`id_feature_value`
                FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product` p
                    ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
                ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
                '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
                '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $context->shop).'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` cl
                    ON (product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
                    AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang` pl
                    ON (p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
                    AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image` i
                    ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)'.
                Shop::addSqlAssociation('image', 'i', false, 'image_shop.cover=1').'
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'image_lang` il
                    ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image`
                    AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.')
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer` m
                    ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer`
                LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'ps_feature_product` fp
                    ON p.`id_product` = fp.`id_product`
                WHERE product_shop.`id_shop` = '.(int)$context->shop->id.'
                    AND cp.`id_category` = '.(int)$this->id
                    .($active ? ' AND product_shop.`active` = 1' : '')
                    .($front ? ' AND product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")' : '')
                    .($id_supplier ? ' AND p.id_supplier = '.(int)$id_supplier : '')
                    .' GROUP BY product_shop.id_product';
```

The table `ps_feature_product` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_feature_product` (
  `id_feature` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_feature_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_feature`,`id_product`,`id_feature_value`),
  KEY `id_feature_value` (`id_feature_value`),
  KEY `id_product` (`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table contains lots of different product features, but I need the features with `id_feature_value` 4 till 13 and that ID can be used as sort order as well.
So far no problem, a simple WHERE clause does the trick:

```
WHERE fp.`id_feature_value` BETWEEN 4 AND 13
```

And the ORDER clause is also straight forward:

```
ORDER BY fp.`id_feature_value` ASC
```

But now the tricky bit. 
Products for which no `id_feature_value` in the range 4-13 is set, should be merged in as well, but they should be sorted to the end of the list.

And it's this last bit of the query that I cannot wrap my head around. 
How do I select features within a range and at the same time select features NOT within that range and add a sort order.

Comment: Sounds like an ideal case for UNION. Select the features within the range UNION the features outside the range.

Comment: I am unsure how a UNION could fix my problem but maybe I am overlooking something. Or maybe I simply don't know enough of all the possibilities of UNION.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this include them?

```
WHERE fp.`id_feature_value` BETWEEN 4 AND 13
   OR fp.`id_feature_value` IS NULL
```

EDIT: sorry, i misunderstood what you meant by "for which no ... is set".

I think you want to add something to your `SELECT` list upon which you can sort, like

```
IF(fp.`id_feature_value` BETWEEN 4 AND 13, 0, 1) AS my_sort
```

and then include `my_sort ASC` in your sort.

simplified example:

```
mysql> create table so1 (n integer);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

mysql> insert into so1 values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(NULL);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select n, if(n between 2 and 4, 0, 1) AS s from so1 order by s ASC, n;
+------+---+
| n    | s |
+------+---+
|    2 | 0 |
|    3 | 0 |
|    4 | 0 |
| NULL | 1 |
|    1 | 1 |
|    5 | 1 |
+------+---+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: No that won't work. It is highly unlikely that no feature value at all is set for any product. If I could ad something like OR (fp.`id_feature_value` BETWEEN 4 AND 13) IS NULL, that would be the solution I guess.

Comment: sorry, @Mattie - oops. i misunderstood the question. updated.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but I thought the IF sets the value for `my_sort` to either 0 or 1 in this example? I need to keep the real value of `id_feature_value` because that is going to be decisive for the sort order.

Comment: the idea is to first sort by the 0/1, partitioning the results, then *sub-sort* by the real value.

Comment: or if you explicitly don't want the "non-between" partition sorted, make the sort-key something like `if(n between 2 and 4, n, 100)` and don't sub-sort

Comment: yes. like in my "simplified example". doesn't that do what you want? or maybe i'm still misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was talking about in my comment:
It will automatically give you the results you seek: 4-13 first, then NON 4-13 glommed on at the end of the listing

```
SELECT
<<query details>>
WHERE fp.`id_feature_value` BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
ORDER BY fp.`id_feature_value` ASC
UNION
SELECT
<<query details>>
WHERE fp.`id_feature_value` NOT BETWEEN 4 AND 13 
ORDER BY fp.`id_feature_value` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Chris. I will have to look into the UNION a bit deeper I guess.